# "error ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found" while inserting data

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to insert data into table and this error showed up. This is my table:

Table contains Attraction:

```
CREATE TABLE "ATTRACTION_MH"(
"AttractionNo" NUMBER(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
"CityName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"AttractionName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"Category" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"AllocatedTime" NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ENABLE,
CONSTRAINT "UC_Attraction" UNIQUE ("AttractionName"),
CHECK ("AttractionNo"<=5 AND "AttractionNo">=1),
CHECK ("AllocatedTime"<=180 AND "AllocatedTime">=30)
)
```

Table contains Cities:

```
CREATE TABLE "CITY_MH"
(
    "CityName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
    "TourID" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "HotelName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "NumberOfNights" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CHECK ("NumberOfNights"<=3 AND "NumberOfNights">=1)
)
```

Table contains Tours:

```
CREATE TABLE "TOUR_MH" 
(
    "TourID" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
    "TourTitle" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "Cost" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 2000 NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CHECK ("Cost"<= 2500 AND "Cost">=1500)
);

ALTER TABLE "CITY_MH"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_TourID"
FOREIGN KEY ("TourID") REFERENCES "TOUR_MH"("TourID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "ATTRACTION_MH"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_CityName"
FOREIGN KEY ("CityName") REFERENCES "CITY_MH"("CityName") ENABLE;
```

Then, I am trying to execute following statement and error appears:

```
INSERT INTO TOUR_MH ('TourID', 'TourTitle', 'Cost') VALUES
(1, 'Around Poland', 2500),
(2, 'The Netherlands Tour', 2100),
(3, 'England Trip', 1500),
(4, 'Spain Tour', 2150),
(5, 'Italy Trip', 1900);
```

Comment: either your CityName or TourID aren't in their respective parent tables. Also, if your FK is CityName, what happens you have two cities of the same name, like Paris France and Paris WV USA - better to have an ID (number) field there as name is generally not ever going to be unique.

Comment: That `insert` statement is going to generate a different error message in Oracle - it does not support multi-row inserts like that

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, FK needs to be CityName, it was specified by my module leader. How to make CityName, TourID in their respective parent table?

Comment: Just remember that's not how it's done in the real world.

Comment: the fk's you have on ATTRACTION_MH and CITY_MH are pointing to values you have in TOUR_MH. TOUR_MH itself doesn't have any FKs, so you should be able to insert. Please share the insert and error message you're getting. That INSERT you show isn't valid either. Each row is a different INSERT statement.

Comment: By the way, Oracle names are case-insensitive by default, with double-quoting only provided in case for some twisted reason you really do need to name your table something like `"MixedCase with spaces!"`. As a rule this is something best avoided unless human life is directly at risk.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, Thanks for explanation. I managed to fix it. I also used different INSERT statement for each row.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson "unless human life is directly at risk" LOL - and even then they might die b/c someone screws it up!